# Es juckt ihm oder ihn in den Fingern?

Tags: idiom

According to [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/jdn++jdm+juckt+es+in+den+Fingern+etw+zu+tun.html), this expression can either be used with *jemandem* or with *jemanden*. Which one should a person use? Is there any different at all in the two? Does any one of them sound better than the other?

Answer (score 6):

In my personal experience, people in Baden-Württemberg prefer the Dativ ("es juckt mir/ihm"), whereas in Berlin people use the Akkusativ ("es juckt mich/ihn").

Both Duden and Wiktionary list the version with dativ first, but I don't think this is relevant. Both versions are correct!

[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/jucken) writes:

> es juckt mir, auch mich in den Fingern

and [wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/es_juckt_jemandem_in_den_Fingern):

> es juckt jemandem in den Fingern,
>
> Alternative Schreibweisen: es juckt jemanden in den Fingern

Comment: I don't even think the usage is regionally diverse - It's maybe just a matter of personal preference - And I keep finding myself using both forms...

Comment: But Berlin dialect typically avoids *mich* altogether in favour of *mir* …

Comment: @Jan, the reason might be that most of my friends/collegues in Berlin are not from Berlin....

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Universität Leipzig](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/cgi-portal/de/wort_www?site=22&Wort_id=6567231&bl=208) it is "es juckt ihn in den Fingern".

There *might* be regional differences though. It is not yet in the [Atlas Alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/register/), so if you are *really* interested, you might ask them to include this idiom in the next survey.

Comment: I've heard both (near Frankfurt/Hessen).